# C++ STL Deque search: too slow?

Tags: c++, stl, deque, function-call

I'm currently taking a course on competitive progamming. I came across a function-call question where one task requires me to find a value within a deque. Unfortunately, my current implementation has time complexity `O(N)` and it is too slow.

My code is as such:

```
deque<int>::iterator find(int ref) {
    for (deque<int>::iterator it = d.begin(); it != d.end(); ++it) {
        if (*it == ref) return it;
    }
    return d.begin();
}
```

After asking around, I figured out that I needed logarithmic time complexity `O(log N)` in order to avoid Time Limit Exceeded (TLE) error. Please help, thank you!

Comment: you seem to be using the wrong data structure. For O(log N) lookup, you'll need a sorted data structure.

Comment: As @SanderDeDycker said, consider storing your ints sorted and then you can use std::binary_search which has logarithmic complexity.

Comment: Are you allowed to construct the deque yourself? Can you make any assumptions about the contents of the deque? If not, then there is no faster than linear algorithm. By the way, returning begin iterator if the target is not found is just silly. How can you tell if the first element is a match or no match was found?

Comment: Any reason you don't use `std::find`? Seems strange to roll out your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if content is sorted you can use binary search: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search
ot change deque on map: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/  (Logarithmic in size.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The question required for the elements to be not sorted, so the map worked.